# jQuery each loop with has()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a class to an anchor if it contains an image - but it's adding the class to every anchor regardless:

```
    $(".entry-content a").each( function(i, link) {

        if ($(link).has("img")) {
            $(link).addClass("fancybox");                   
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be

```
$(".entry-content a").has("img").addClass("fancybox");
```

[.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) returns a jQuery object, so it will always be truthy. It filters the given set of elements based on whether an element contains an element which satisfies the passed selctor/set.

So to add the class you can just chain the `addClass()` to the value returned by `.has()`

Using :has-selector

```
$(".entry-content a:has(img)").addClass("fancybox");
```